# jQuery not working in Safari/Chrome with AJAX control on the page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm using this code for both horizontal and vertical slider controls on different pages for a simple site.  It works on all pages in IE and Firefox; but on one page in Safari and Chrome, it fails.  That page has an AJAX control (pop-up for Facebook share).  When I removed the script manager and the AJAX control, the jQuery script executed perfectly.

How do I fix this script so it will execute with an AJAX control on the page?

Here is the script:

```
<script>
var over = false;
var intervalID = 0;
$("#btn_Right").hover(
  function() {
    over = true;
    DoMove("Left");
  },
  function() {
    over = false;
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
);

$("#btn_Left").hover(
  function() {
    over = true;
    DoMove("Right");
  },
  function() {
    over = false;
    clearInterval(intervalID);
  }
);

function DoMove(direction) {
  var interval = 600;
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    if (over)
      MoveFrames(direction);
  }, interval);
}

function MoveFrames(direction) {
  var itemWidth = 175;
  var viewFrameWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById('ViewFrame').style.width);
  var containerWidth = parseInt(document.getElementById('Container').style.width);
  var CurrentPos = parseInt(document.getElementById('Container').style.marginLeft);
  if (CurrentPos % itemWidth == 0) {
    if ((direction == "Left" && CurrentPos <= -(containerWidth - viewFrameWidth)) || (direction == "Right" && CurrentPos >= 0)) {
      clearInterval(intervalID);
    }
    else {
      if (direction == "Left") {
        $("#Container").animate({ marginLeft: '-=175' }, 400);
      }
      else if (direction == "Right") {
        $("#Container").animate({ marginLeft: '+=175' }, 400);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add that the script executes all the way to the animate code, but nothing happens...

Comment: what was the id of your script manager and ajax control?

Comment: ScriptManager1...could that be a problem??

Comment: The ajax popup control is ModalPopupExtender1.  The button ids that trigger the ajax popup are imageButton_Connect, lbn_ShareUpper.

Comment: maybe is a conflict error. Try the noconflic jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think you've run into a known compatibility bug - check this resource for a work around!

http://blog.turlov.com/2009/01/aspnet-ajax-compatibility-patch-for.html